# Deleting a cell in a table in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, cell

I have created a table called "valtable2" and I am trying to delete the text in one of the cells.

```
With valtable2
  .Cell(2, 1).Select
  Selection.Delete
End With
With valtable2
  .Cell(2, 1).Select
  Selection.Delete
End With
```

The cell is being selected, but it doesn't delete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete cell contents in Word with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878294/how-to-delete-cell-contents-in-word-with-vba)

Comment: The answer in the linked post encourages the use of Select, which can be avoided in this instance

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using `Select` where possible. You could just set the cell value to nothing:

```
valtable2.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = ""
```